# Custom grouping by taxonomy term in view

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I made a view with taxonomy and nodes, groupped like this:

```
term 1
    subterm 1
        row
        row
term 2
    subterm 1
        row
        row
term 3
    subterm 1
        row
        row
    subterm 2
        row
        row
term 4
    subterm 1
        row
        row
```

But I need grouping by term like this:

```
term 1
    row
    row
term 2
    row
    row
term 3
    subterm 1
        row
        row
    subterm 2
        row
        row
term 4
    row
term 5
    row
    etc.
```

please any ideas, i wasted a lot of time to find the hook and tpl.php for this (tpl. or hooks - ?)

Answer (score 1):

Groping things in view not that easy, and what i suggest you here to save your time to use views_field_view which allowed you to insert view inside view.

So simply make 3 displays each one for level and pass the argument between them, that should not take more than 5 min